# How to reset a variable to initial value after while loop

Tags: python-3.x

So I am playing around making a hashtag tree.

```
 #Ask user to enter number of tree rows
    Height=int(input("Enter height of tree: "))
    hashes = 1
    while Height >0:
        print(' ' * (Height-1) + "#" * (hashes))
        Height -=1
        hashes +=2
    #print a stump(hash)
    print(" " * (Height) + "#")
```

It seems that for the last print the value assigned in Height variable is 0. It has kept the value decremented in the while loop. How can I reset it after the while loop back to its initial value?

Answer (score 0):

Save its value before the loop:

```
    Height=int(input("Enter height of tree: "))
    hashes = 1
    h = Height
    while Height >0:
        print(' ' * (Height-1) + "#" * (hashes))
        Height -=1
        hashes +=2
    #print a stump(hash)
    print(" " * (h-1) + "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `while` loop, loop over `range(Height-1, -1, -1)` with a seperate loop variable

```
height = int(input("Enter height of tree: "))
for hashes, curr_height in enumerate(range(height-1, -1, -1)):
    print((' ' * curr_height) + ('#' * (2*hashes + 1)))
print(' ' * (height-1) + '#')
```